# Guaranteeing a response from observable before execute next line

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to wait for an API call from an observable before proceeding to the next line of code/function. I am unable to do this, however promise works with await.
Here is my code so far:

```
 async validateDataObservable(email: string) {
    await this.userProfileService.getUserByEmail().subscribe((val: any) => {
      console.log('Hello');
    });
    console.log('Execute after Hello');

    // Output:
    // Execute after Hello
    // Hello
  }
```

This is unfortunately not the desired output behavior.

Code below works but I need the same functionality for Observables due to a requirement.

```
  async validateDataPromise(email: string) {
    await this.userProfileService.getUserByEmailPro(email).then((val: any) => {
      console.log('Hello');
    });
    console.log('Execute after Hello');

    // Output:
    // Hello
    // Execute after Hello
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: is it not possible for you to put the `console.log('Execute after Hello');` line inside the `then()` function? then it would always be executed after the first function.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to move `console.log('Execute after Hello')` inside the `subscribe` callback, just after `console.log('Hello')`.

Comment: You can use `toPromise()` but it means that the source Observable has to complete.

Answer (score 0):

`await` is a Promise-feature, so sadly you can't do this with Observables. You can use `.toPromise()` if you really want this functionality, but it's not recommended. You should put your code inside the `subscribe` body (or inside a `map`).

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Comment: Because observables are more powerful, and they can be cancelled if not needed anymore. Of course, there is little harm in doing this conversion here, but you shouldn't make it a habit. it's unnecessary overhead and clutters the code too IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Behavior/Asyn Subject and write the code in complete. Something like below:

```
validateDataPromise(email: string) {
  this.userProfileService.getUserByEmailPro(email)
  .takeUntil(this.unSub)
  .subscribe((val: any) => {
    console.log('Hello');
  }, (error: Error) => {
    console.error('Error');
  }, () => {
    console.log('Execute after Hello');
  });
}
```

References: 
https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#asyncsubject

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. Get rest of the code (code which you want to execute after console.log('hello') ) to a function .and call the function inside subscribe after calling 
console.log('hello'). Or you can just put rest of the code inside the subscribe after console.log('hello).

```
async validateDataPromise(email: string) {
    await this.userProfileService.getUserByEmailPro(email).then((val: any) => {
      console.log('Hello');
      this.doRest()
    });


    // Output:
    // Hello
    // Execute after Hello
  }

doRest(){
  console.log('Execute after Hello');
 // implement what you want after asynchronous call.
}
```